# Android listview should have same imageview size

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to know whats the best approach for imageview size in listview. If I want to keep the imageview same irrespective of aspect ratio/image pixel,size. Somewhat like **whatsapp** does.

What is the best possible solution?

**options**

1. Set parameters in layout xml file.
2. Programatically.
3. Make custom image with fixed size and use that in layout

Comment: Did you face any problem while using custom layout?

Comment: @Aniruddha i tried parameters layout width and height of imageview. even tried with scale fitxy. but no luck. I am displaying image from sdcard in listview

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the **layout**(Option 1) that it can scale your photo without any calculation to the screen, through setting the the adjustViewBounds to true so you can still preserve its aspect ration.

as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds) for it:

```
Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.
```

Comment: If the image size is less i.e 2,3kb then also  the image should be scaled up to fix the imageview size specified

Comment: @AshishBhatia you cant scale that up without losing any aspect ratio. even if you do it programatically.

Comment: even if i lose aspect ratio its fine with me, as long as the display is consistent. for images with higher size or lower size the imageview size should be same.

Comment: @AshishBhatia then you can specify the height and width of it. in the layout. that will keep the size the same.